# JSF rendered component not binding with ajax call

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I need help to render a component that will in turn make an ajax call after it has been rendered but with no success.
I have the following code which doesn't work. I don't know if I am missing something. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
 <h:selectOneMenu id="gender" value="#{bean.gender}"  
     class="form-control"
     valueChangeListener="#{bean.updateGenderValue}" 
     onchange="submit()">

   <f:selectItems value="#{bean.genders}" var="gender" itemLabel="#
      {gender}" itemValue="#{gender}"/>                                                               
 </h:selectOneMenu> 

 <h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.pregnancyStatus}"  
    class="form-control"
    rendered="#{bean.gender eq 'Female'}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.options}" 
      var="pregnancyStatus" itemLabel="#{pregnancyStatus}" 
       itemValue="#{pregnancyStatus}"/>

   <f:ajax listener="#{bean.updatePregancyValue}" 
            execute="@this" render="@this"/>

</h:selectOneMenu> 


 public void updateGenderValue(ValueChangeEvent event) throws IOException {
    gender = (String) event.getNewValue();
 }

        public void updatePregancyValue(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) throws IOException {                                                                            
      System.out.println(":( == " + pregnancyStatus);
      }
```

The pregnancyStatus value is never updated at all.

Answer (score 1):

Did you missed the `<h:form>`? I copied and pasted your code in my project and

my code:

```
<div style="height:500px">
<h:form>

<h:selectOneMenu id="gender" value="#{bean.gender}"  
 class="form-control"
 valueChangeListener="#{bean.updateGenderValue}" 
 onchange="submit()">



<f:selectItems value="#{bean.genders}" var="gender" itemLabel="#
      {gender}" itemValue="#{gender}"/>                                                               
 </h:selectOneMenu> 

 <h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.pregnancyStatus}"  
    class="form-control"
    rendered="#{bean.gender eq 'Female'}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.options}" 
      var="pregnancyStatus" itemLabel="#{pregnancyStatus}" 
       itemValue="#{pregnancyStatus}"/>

   <f:ajax listener="#{bean.updatePregancyValue}" 
            execute="@this" render="@this"/>

</h:selectOneMenu>
```

lets check the console :

```
:( == 2
:( == 3
```

Bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "bean")
@ViewScoped
public class Bean {

    private String pregnancyStatus;
    private List<SelectItem> options;
    private List<SelectItem> genders;
    private String gender;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initBean(){
        options = new ArrayList<>();
        genders = new ArrayList<>();
        options.add(new SelectItem("1"));
        options.add(new SelectItem("2"));
        options.add(new SelectItem("3"));
        genders.add(new SelectItem("Male"));
        genders.add(new SelectItem("Female"));
        genders.add(new SelectItem("third"));
    }

    public String getPregnancyStatus() {
        return pregnancyStatus;
    }

    public void setPregnancyStatus(String pregnancyStatus) {
        this.pregnancyStatus = pregnancyStatus;
    }

    public void updateGenderValue(ValueChangeEvent event) throws IOException {
        gender = (String) event.getNewValue();
    }

    public void updatePregancyValue(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(":( == " + pregnancyStatus);
    }

}
```

Comment: what does your `onchange="submit()` do? It's unclear what it does in the OP's question. Better to ask the OP to create a [mcve].... You should not have to 'try' and get things clear. But thanks for trying to help!!!

Comment: My parameter list in the submit looks like this :j_idt9 j_idt9
j_idt9:gender Female
j_idt9:j_idt11 3
javax.faces.ViewState 3848250333621752611:-7307656456661206570
javax.faces.source j_idt9:j_idt11
javax.faces.partial.event change
javax.faces.partial.execute j_idt9:j_idt11
javax.faces.partial.render j_idt9:j_idt11
javax.faces.behavior.event valueChange
javax.faces.partial.ajax true

Comment: No, what does it **do**? What javascript is called? And where did ypu get the bean from? How do you know it os what OP uses too?

Comment: ahh ok. No javascript is called. I did not implemented the onsubmit() function because in my point of view it is not needed. JSF makes the job

Comment: Yes, but it might do something for OP and mess thingd up/ Hence always ask for a [mcve]. Saves you  time guessing and trying ;-)

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow. Thx for the advice

Comment: After spending 3 days trying to find the problem, I was missing the @SessionScoped annotation, once I added that, the values were now being updated. Your answer helped me remember the scope type, that is what I was missing. Thank you guys for your help.